# .js.erb file won't precompile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, asset-pipeline

When I try to run `rake assets precompile` I get this error: `Unexpected token: operator (>)`.
I figured out it was because of index.js.erb, because changing the name of the file to .html.erb made it compile.
This is the content of index.js.erb:

```
$('#haikus').append('<%= j render(@haikus) %>');
<% if @haikus.next_page %>
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@haikus) %>');
<% else %>
$('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

haikus.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
if $('.pagination').length
      $(window).scroll ->
              url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
              if url &&  $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200
                      $('.pagination').html('Loading...')
                      $.getScript(url)
$(window).scroll()
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="haikus">
<%= render @haikus %>
</div>
<div class="row pagination">
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <%= will_paginate @haikus %>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I fix it and make it compile?

Thanks!

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: The error is on line 15748 (full error: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 15748, col: 8, pos: 468462)

Comment: lol ok that wasn't as helpful as I had hoped it would be :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this has a lot  to do with it:

> changing the name of the file to .html.erb made it compile

Have you tried removing the logic from your js.erb file? I really thinking about the "`will_paginate`" stuff not able to be called from a javascript file. Maybe you could just have this line in the file & see if that compiles?

```
$('#haikus').append('<%= j render(@haikus) %>');
```

If that doesn't work, then we know it's something to do with this; else it will be something to do with the will_paginate most likely

Comment: It precompiles if I leave this line of code, so it has something to do with will_paginate

Comment: Why don't you try just putting this code into your js.erb: <% if @haikus.next_page %> alert("next page"); <% end %> --> see if that compiles

Comment: The problem you might have is that will_paginate is I think will_paginate is only for views & controllers; not JS or models. I'm not entirely sure though

Comment: I followed the railcasts tutorial for this. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You'll have to describe it a bit more thoroughly in order for me to help you I'm afraid :) Got any more info you can give me?